# Apache error (Segmentation fault) when I run PHP program in browser

Tags: php

With the following configuration, I am trying to run a program which connects to SQL Server using PDO_ODBC extension
PHP 5.5.21
Apache 2.4.18
Running on Red Hat Linux 6.8

I am getting this error. Some time it executes successfully but most of the run gives the following error in error_log

[core:notice] [pid 5789] AH00052: child pid 2502 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

If I run the same snippet on Windows machine (Local setup), it is success all the time.
In Windows I have PHP 5.6.30, Apache 2.4.25

If I run the same program with just php command, it is working fine on Linux

```
<?php
 $user="test";
 $pass="1234";
 try{
  $conn = new PDO("odbc:Test", $user, $pass);
 }
 catch(PDOException $exception){
  $exception->getMessage();
}
echo "Connected Successfully";
unset($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Segmentation faults are often core bugs of the language or the modules it depends on. PHP 5.5 is now completely outdated and I'd suggest upgrading to PHP 7 if you can, and at least the very last PHP 5.6 subversion if you really can't switch to 7 for the time being. It might still be something else though (such as the ODBC driver; make sure it's up to date too).

Comment: Thanks, @Jeto for your suggestion. Will surely think of upgrading the version. When I run as a PHP program in a command line, it works fine without any issues. The problem happens when the same program run in a browser where it is making use of Apache.

Comment: I can't use sqlsrv for php 5.5 on Lunx. From the various threads, I learned that sqlsrv is for PHP7.0+ when comes to Linux OS.